# Re-resolve a scala config object

Tags: scala, typesafe-config

I would like to re-resolve a config object.
for example if I define this config:

```
val conf = ConfigFactory.parseString(
  """
    | foo = a
    | bar = ${foo}1
    | baz = ${foo}2
  """.stripMargin).resolve()
```

I will get those values:

```
conf.getString("bar") //res0: String = a1
conf.getString("baz") //res1: String = a2
```

given the object `conf`, what I want is to be able to change the value of `foo`, and get updated values for `bar` and `baz`.
Something like :

```
val conf2 = conf
             .withValue("foo", ConfigValueFactory.fromAnyRef("b"))
             .resolve()
```

and get:

```
conf2.getString("bar") //res0: String = b1
conf2.getString("baz") //res1: String = b2
```

but running this code will result in:

```
conf2.getString("foo") //res0: String = b
conf2.getString("bar") //res1: String = a1
conf2.getString("baz") //res2: String = a2
```

is this even possible?

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible once `resolve` is called.  In [the documentation for `resolve`](http://typesafehub.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/Config.html#resolve--), it says:

> Returns a replacement config with all substitutions resolved... Resolving an already-resolved config is a harmless no-op.

In other words, once you call `resolve`, all the substitions occur, and there is no reference to the original [HOCON](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#value-concatenation) substitution syntax.

Of course, you can keep the unresolved `Config` object as a variable, and then use `withValue`:

```
val rawConf = ConfigFactory.parseString(
  """
    | foo = a
    | bar = ${foo}1
    | baz = ${foo}2
  """.stripMargin)
val conf2 = rawConf.withValue("foo", ConfigValueFactory.fromAnyRef("b")).resolve
val conf = rawConf.resolve

conf.getString("bar") //a1
conf2.getString("bar") //b1, as desired
```

Comment: my code is at a place where the config is already resolved, and I don't want change all the other places that use this config object

Comment: @lev Then it's not possible, I believe!